# Get all bold words from excel column with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Is it possible to get words that are bold in the excel fields when using Pandas function pd.read_excel for reading the file?

I get all rows with function df.itertuples().

I want in each row to get all words that are bold in the second column.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You would need additional package.

```
from styleframe import StyleFrame

df = StyleFrame.read_excel('test.xlsx', read_style=True, use_openpyxl_styles=False)

for text in df["Colname"]: # replace Colname
    if text.style.bold:
        print(text)
```

reference [StyleFrame](https://github.com/deepspace2/StyleFrame)

Comment: This is not working very well.. It keeps returning False for the field that is bold.

Comment: I switched to xlrd. I have loaded file with load_workbook() and set formatting_info=True. When file is loaded like that, sheet objects have an attribute rich_text_runlist_map which solved my problem. 
Thanks anyway :)